# How to retrieve models data having nested relationship using serializers in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i am explaining in detail about a problem that i am facing and seek help from this community. I followed this  [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) but couldn't get the desired result for multi-level nesting

Consider the relationship of models as explained :

1. A user can have multiple Workspaces
2. A workspace can have multiple Projects
3. A Project can have multiple ProjectLists
4. ProjectList can have multiple Tasks
5. Tasks can have multiple updates

`User
    |
    Workspaces (ForeignKey="User")
            |____Projects (ForeignKey="Workspaces")
                        |____TodoList (ForeignKey="Projects")
                                    |____Tasks (ForeignKey="TodoList")
                                            |____Updates (ForeignKey="Tasks")`

**So what i want is to get all the data that a User has in a nested json format like this:**

```
[
    {
        "workspace_id": "99a961ec-b89e-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459",
        "workspace_owner": "1",
        "workspace_title": "Indie Dev Works",
        "projects": [
            {
                "project_id":"db09cfa0-b89e-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459",
                "todo_list":[
                    {
                        "list_id": "9dc64e4c-b89f-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459",
                        "list_name":"Project list -1",
                        "tasks":[
                            "task_name":"Create HTML docs",
                            "updates":[
                                {
                                    "id":"d5eb660e-b89f-11e8-96f8-529269fb1459",
                                    "text":"Creating using PUG"
                                },
                                {
                                    .....
                                    .....
                                    .....
                                    .....

                                },

                            ]

                        ]
                    }
                ]

            },

            {
                "project_id":".........",
                ....
                ....
                ....
                ..
                ..
                .


            },
        ]

    }
]
```

So when my User logs in by entering email, i am trying to get all the Workspaces instance and then pass it to the serializers
in my views as mentioned below:

**views.py**

```
class InitializeHome(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self,request):
        user_email = request.user.email
        user_instance = utils.getUserInstance(user_email)
        workspace_instance = WorkSpace.objects.filter(workspace_owner=user_instance)

        testing_serializer = WorkSpaceSerializer(workspace_instance,many=True)
        return Response(testing_serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        # depth = 2        
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Update


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    updates = UpdateSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        # depth = 2        
        fields = '__all__'   
        model = Task


class ProjectTodoListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        # depth = 2        
        fields =  '__all__'
        model = ProjectTodoListItem


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    project_todo_list = ProjectTodoListItemSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)                
    class Meta:
        # depth = 2        
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Project


class WorkSpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        # depth = 2

        model = WorkSpace
        fields = '__all__'
```

**What I am getting is only this and none of the nested Arrays :**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "workspace_title": "Indie Dev Work",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "workspace_id": "26c60d80-c018-403c-84b2-d92f01f6fb7e",
        "workspace_owner": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "workspace_title": "Homework Space",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "workspace_id": "08c715cc-bd24-46d3-a1dd-14cf7ff28215",
        "workspace_owner": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
By adding `source="workspace_set"` in **all** the Serializer classes, the results can be achieved:-

```
class WorkSpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True,read_only=True,source="workspace_set")
    class Meta:
        # depth = 2

        model = WorkSpace
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can help me to solve nested array problem    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008694/multi-nested-with-django-restframework-and-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment113195953_64008694

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way too:

```
class WorkSpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        # depth = 2

        model = WorkSpace
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_projects(self, obj): # get_YOUR_FIELD_NAME
        return ProjectSerializer(obj.projects.all(), many=True).data
```

and same for other classes.

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work and i can't really test it right now but you can try naming the fields in your meta class (it should't make any difference but you can try it)

Comment: hey there , thanks for replying . If we add the source parameter to the serializer class then we can get the desired result. Check out my answer