# Multi Nested with Django Restframework and Mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views, djongo

**I want output like this. I have a task to complete more than 5 models with nested type and all CRUD methods by using RestFawork.If anyone knows the answer share with me.**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "John 1",
    "last_name": "Robert 1",
    "instrument": "KeyBoard",
    "album_musician": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "artist": 1,
            "name": "Test robert",
            "release_date": "2020-09-16",
            "num_stars": 400
             "Language": [
                  {
                   
                     
                     "Original": "English",
                     "Dubbed": "Tamil"
           
                 }

    ]
        }
        
    ]
}
```

In this Code, I did only Sigle Nested Framework.
My model.py

Serializer.py
In this Serialization, I used the CRUD method

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('id', 'artist', 'name', 'release_date', 'num_stars')


class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_musician = AlbumSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Musician
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'instrument', 'album_musician')
        lookup_field=id

    def create(self, validated_data):
        albums_data = validated_data.pop('album_musician')
        musician = Musician.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for album_data in albums_data:
            Album.objects.create(artist=musician, **album_data)
        return musician

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        albums_data = validated_data.pop('album_musician')
        albums = (instance.album_musician).all()
        albums = list(albums)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.instrument = validated_data.get('instrument', instance.instrument)
        instance.save()

        for album_data in albums_data:
            album = albums.pop(0)
            album.name = album_data.get('name', album.name)
            album.release_date = album_data.get('release_date', album.release_date)
            album.num_stars = album_data.get('num_stars', album.num_stars)
            album.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Can you post your models.py and also views.py?

Comment: @KamarulAdha  https://django.cowhite.com/blog/create-and-update-django-rest-framework-nested-serializers/ please check this link. This code only I have implemented . This is single nested but I want multi inner nested.